# Is there a way to reference the function you are inside of in C?

Tags: c, function, this, arduino

I am writing a function that just looks up values inside of a table. Is it possible to call that function inside of itself? I've seen stuff about `this` and `self` and don't really understand it.

Comment: Reference as in "call" or as in "take a pointer to?"

Comment: `this` is only available in C++ and `self` only in Objective-C. Those aren't C. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can. It's called recursion.

```
void foo(){
   foo(); //This is legal.
}
```

Of course you need to return from it to avoid infinite recursive calls. Failing to return will cause a stack overflow. Here's a better example:

```
void foo(int n){
    if (n == 0)
        return;
    foo(--n);
}
```

Comment: To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion.

Comment: This will never return either, unless `n` was initially zero.  `n--` returns `n` and then decrements it.  I think you meant `--n`.

Comment: @link664 To use recursion, you must first use recursion.

Answer (score 5):

See *[Recursion (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)* (Wikipedia).

An example of calling a function inside a function:

```
# include<stdio.h>

int factorial(unsigned int number)
{
    if (number <= 1)
        return 1;
    return number * factorial(number - 1);
}

void main()
{
    int x = 5;
    printf("factorial of %d is %d",x,factorial(x));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have answered your question, but since it was alien to you, you might want to read up on recursion and recursive functions. There are some gotchas that may catch you if you are not aware.

The worst of which is that you can quickly overflow your stack if you are too deep, or if your function stack-allocates a lot of things. If you are planning to use a recursive implementation make sure your recursion is bounded and that you allocate the bare minimum on the stack.

You might want to consider an iterative approach - every recursive problem can be solved iteratively with some thought. It's usually an interesting exercise to do as well.

JoshLeaves has said that recursion is faster, but often it's not because of the need to allocate grow stack and set up registers. If your function makes two or more calls to itself to calculate its result then an iterative solution is always faster.

Comment: +1 for the shoutout to iteration. Generally more efficient. Tail recursion is just as fast but C doesn't have that.

Comment: I see why this is an issue, but the function is just looking up a value from a table. It's simple and not stack overflowing.

Comment: @Kyle Hotchkiss: If your function 'n' times based on some input 'n' then make 'n' really big and watch it explode. Alternately stick it somewhere with a really small stack. Recursion is pretty dangerous unless it's very strictly bounded.

Comment: @ThelronKnuckle: GCC, at least, will do tail call optimizations in some cases. Knowing what it is and how to craft your function can sometimes be useful. Still better to be iterative where you can.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Okay, I thought this was about "getting every function value". As other posters said, this is called recursion. A few notes though:

Recursion is faster than iteration (I don't have benchmark results on hand, but I ran them one year ago on an [Intel Core i5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i5)).

```
//Iteration
function do_stuff(i)
{
    //BLABLAH
}

for (i = 0; i <5; i++) {
    do_stuff();
}

//Recursion
function do_stuff(int i)
{
    //BLABLAH
    if (i < 5) {
        do_stuff(i + 1);
    }
}
```

- You can recurse multiple times but you have to find a way to make the recursion stop or...
- If your recursion goes down too far (think "Inception" times a million...), you run into the risk of overflowing your available stack memory just by entering the same function a millionth time.

Comment: That gives you the *name* of the current function (as a character array `char[]`).  OP just wants a function to call itself recursively; *maybe* he wants to obtain a function pointer to the current function.

Comment: @Adam Sorry, yeah I saw that and changed my answer to add some "wisdom" to the use of recursive functions.

Comment: Recursion can only possibly be faster than iteration when performing a tailcall.  Otherwise, the extra stack frame allocation and register reinitialization will kill any performance advantage.

Comment: @cdhowie Never heard about this before, all my recursive functions used return values. Thanks for the info.